# Subclass 600 Processing time changed

Tags: australia, tourist-visas, pakistani-citizens

I have applied for Subclass 600 (tourist) Visa on Jan 30th, 2019. The processing time was showing 15-27 days when I submitted the application. Today when I logged into my immi account now its showing 18-29 days. I have got no information about this processing time change in my immi portal nor over the internal. 
Is this very usual or something happening only with me?

Answer (score 2):

The processing time displayed is calculated from the actual processing time of applications submitted in the preceding few weeks. It will vary, and in a few days it may be longer or shorter than you see today.

You can find the full details on the [Australian Immigration web site](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-processing-times/global-visa-processing-times)

You should hear something in four to six weeks. If you haven't, contact them again.

Comment: I haven't found any details regarding contacting them about the status, do you have any URL with more information or where I can submit a request after 4 weeks.